# Magento 2 Ui Component Date Field Saves current date

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, date

Magento 2 Ui component Date Fields save the current date not saved the inputed date please show my below code

Form

```
 <field name="active_from_date" formElement="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">program</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">From</label>
            <dataScope>active_from_date</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>

    <field name="active_to_date" formElement="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">program</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">To</label>
            <dataScope>active_to_date</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

and save action

```
 public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $model = $this->programRepository->getById($id);
        } else {
            unset($data['id']);
            $model = $this->programFactory->create();
        }

        try {
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray($model, $data, ProgramInterface::class);
            $this->programRepository->save($model);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved this data.'));
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

Please help me

Comment: It's magento2's default issue. They have already generated ticket for it.https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17564

Comment: I am ask for form not for grid